# Quasar sigened apk refused by Google play store

Tags: apk, signed, quasar

i’m unable to publish my app in google play store, trying to sign my apk with 10000 days, but when upload in play store getting an error “You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle signed with a certificate that expires too soon. You need to sign your APK or Android App Bundle with a certificate that expires farther into the future.” please help me…

Comment: Could you share how you created your keystore? What command did you run? Also, are you sure you are signing with that keystore? What is your gradle config?

Comment: `keytool -genkey -v -keystore <keystoreName>.keystore -alias <Keystore AliasName> -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000`                                                                
                                                                                                                        `jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore <keystorename> <Unsigned APK file> <Keystore Alias name>`                                                                               
                           
`zipalign -v 4 Example-release-unsigned.apk Example.apk`

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the validity to at least 20000. Quasars default is at 20000.